# What does the "-no-canonical-prefixes" flag do in clang?

Tags: clang

I have seen that the android NDK build script uses the `-no-canonical-prefixes` clang flag.

What is the purpose of `-no-canonical-prefixes` flag?

I haven't been able to find it in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-no-canonical-prefixes)

> -no-canonical-prefixes
>
> Do not expand any symbolic links, resolve references to ‘/../’ or ‘/./’, or make the path absolute when generating a relative prefix.